# Makefile: all vs default targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Talking with respect to GNU make, what is the difference  between PHONY targets `all:` and `default:`.

```
CC=g++
default: hello

hello: hello.cpp
     $(CC) -o hello hello.cpp
```

and

```
CC=g++
all: hello

hello: hello.cpp
     $(CC) -o hello hello.cpp
```

Both of them do the same job.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can call them `shirley` if you like; neither of the labels you mention has any special semantics.  The default behavior of `make` is to run the first target in the `Makefile` if you don't specify a target as a command-line argument.  If you like to override this behavior, there is the [`.DEFAULT_GOAL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html) special variable.

There is a convention to have a target named `all` which builds everything, but this is just human convention, not a special case or a requirement as far as Make is concerned.

Similarly, there is a (weak) convention to call the default target `default`, but similarly, this is just a human label (and somewhat overlaps and possibly conflicts with the `all` convention).

So the following Makefile does exactly the same thing:

```
.PHONY: shirley all default
default: hello
all: hello
shirley: hello

hello: hello.cpp
# (Make already knows how to build an executable out of a .cpp file)
```

You can omit any or all of the phony targets above, and the only difference will be that humans won't be able to say `make shirley` when they (effectively) mean `make hello`.

Bottom line: Construct your Makefile so that `make` does what a reasonable end-user expects without reading too much `README` files or inspecting the `Makefile`.  Often that will be `make all` (and you should probably have a target with this name, just to satisfy human conventions, even if it's not the default) but this obviously depends on your project and your users' expectations.

> Don't call me Shirley.

Comment: Specifying the `.DEFAULT` special target is **not** the way to override the default goal. The default goal is the first rule in the makefile that does not start with '.' -- unless overridden by specifying the special variable `.DEFAULT_GOAL`. To inform the reader of a very long makefile, it's best to either specify .DEFAULT_GOAL or to write a rule (typically a dummy rule such as `default: all` with no recipe) very early in the makefile.

Comment: @DavidHammen I agree with your final conclusion.  However, I would regard `.DEFAULT_GOAL` hacking as mainly an esoteric back door which should perhaps be avoided, and [the manual's](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html) example of how to use it certainly reinforces this impression.

Comment: @DavidHammen I have suggested an edit; the `.DEFAULT` special target is clearly something different.

Answer (score 7):

The only difference, is that `all` is recommended in the GNU Make manual, to be the first (default) target, and `default` has no such special recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

One is spelled "all" and the other is spelled "default".  There's no other difference between them.  Maybe if you explained why you're asking we'd be able to help more.

Note that in your example above neither of the targets are actually phony.  You'd have to declare them as such:

```
.PHONY: all
```

etc.

Comment: Ya, I didn't specify them as `PHONY`, but were those 2 keywords meant to indicate the same thing? wouldn't that be weird, why would anyone need another if one existed already?

Comment: @qwerty see tripleee's answer: `all` and `default` rules have no special meaning, they're regular rules with regular names.