# What's the usage of "depend" in makefile

Tags: makefile

```
$(obj)u-boot:           depend $(SUBDIRS) $(OBJS) $(LIBBOARD) $(LIBS) $(LDSCRIPT)
                UNDEF_SYM=`$(OBJDUMP) -x $(LIBBOARD) $(LIBS) | \
                sed  -n -e 's/.*\($(SYM_PREFIX)__u_boot_cmd_.*\)/-u\1/p'|sort|uniq`;\
                cd $(LNDIR) && $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $$UNDEF_SYM $(__OBJS) \
                        --start-group $(__LIBS) --end-group $(PLATFORM_LIBS) \
                        -Map u-boot.map -o u-boot
```

what does "depend" do here in the dependency line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, `depend` seems to simply be an arbitrary label which identifies another target further down in the file.

Comment: any official doc to describe this method?

Comment: It's fundamental `make` syntax. Maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242905/makefile-all-vs-default-targets

Comment: negative, it is not the answer for this question.

Comment: No, but it explains how dependency names are essentially random as far as `make` itself is concerned. Without more context in your question (like where you copied this snippet from) I don't think we can tell you more than that the author of that `Makefile` thought these six characters were a useful label there.

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/lentinj/u-boot/blob/master/spl/Makefile line 147

Comment: Agreed that "depend" is simply the name of a prerequisite, with no inherent significance of its own.  Quibble: a rule for building a "depend" target might be anywhere in the file; it could precede the quoted rule instead of following it.

Comment: @tripleee, yes, I copied it from main Makefile of uboot

Comment: @JohnBollinger, so, if it is just a label then why we need it? What benefits does it bring?

Comment: @michael_J, although I agree with tripleee's answer, I think my own wording is clearer: "'depend' is simply the name of a prerequisite".  Because "depend" is a prerequisite, `make` will check and possibly update it (by running its recipe) before running the recipe for the `$(obj)u-boot` target.  Checking and possibly updating a target's prerequisites before updating the target itself is one of the most fundamental aspects of `make`'s behavior.