# How to create a makefile to sort all the .txt files in the directory and save it as .sorted using makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How to create a makefile to sort all the .txt files in the directory and save it as .sorted using makefile?

```
%.sorted: %.txt 
    sort $< -o $@
all: (*.sorted)
default:all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(*.sorted)` is just looking for a file with that literal name. You probably want

```
all: $(patsubst %.txt,%.sorted,$(wildcard *.txt))
%.sorted: %.txt 
    sort $< -o $@
```

The `$(wildcard *.txt)` generates a list of all your text files, and the `$(patsubst ...)` generates a parallel list with `.sorted` instead of `.txt`.

(Notice that Stack Overflow renders tabs as spaces, so you will not be able to simply copy/paste this code from the rendered page.)

For just `make` to do what you want, you need the target to be the first one in the `Makefile`. Perhaps see also [Makefile: all vs default targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242905/makefile-all-vs-default-targets)

Comment: Just to be clear, `(*.sorted)` is not the literal file `(*.sorted)`.  Make allows wildcards in prerequisites and it works as expected.  However, I really don't understand why the OP added the `()` around the wildcard; this is matching file that begin with a `(` and end with `.sorted)` and of course there aren't any of those so this expression expands to the empty string.  This answer is the right answer, I'm just clarifying what actually happens.  Even with just `*.sorted` of course this won't work, because there aren't any sorted files until you create them.