# Make: Rule all without any recipe or dependency

Tags: makefile

I am trying to understand the make files of a system I have because when I try to build it I got a "No such file or directory" for a file that is clearly right there.
So going to the basics my first question is

what does it mean when a makefile has a rule `all:` with nothing else?

like

```
(here a bunch of variables defined andd "mak" files included)

 .PHONY: all
 all:
```

what does this empty all do when I call `make`?

Comment: It simply does nothing. Are you sure the other included files don't declare dependencies for `all` somewhere within?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile: all vs default targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242905/makefile-all-vs-default-targets)

Comment: Just `make` might not execute the `all` rule at all anyway; it runs the first target in the `Makefile` (or an included one, if that's how it ends up being first).

Comment: @tripleee ...or, with GNU make, the one that has been declared with the `.DEFAULT_GOAL` variable.