# make command runs only the first row in Makefile

Tags: c, linux, unix, makefile, terminal

Hi I Have this makefile:

```
main.o:main.c functionsLab1.c functionsLab1.h
    gcc -c main.c
functionsLab1.o: functionsLab1.c functionsLab1.h
        gcc-c functionsLab1.c
```

now when i Run the command "make" it only executes the first command in makefile.

how can I Run all the commands at once?
Thanks in advance :)

I Tried to type "make all" command and it showed an error.

Comment: Read documentation for Make. The first target in Makefile is default.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242905/makefile-all-vs-default-targets/

Comment: If you are building `main.o` with the command `gcc -c main.c`, it would appear that you do not have a dependency on `functionsLab1.c`.  You should be careful about the dependency declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`make` is able to build what you need, but only if you tell it the right dependencies.  In particular, your current Makefile is lying about dependencies, since `main.o` does not at all depend on `functionsLab1.c`.  Rather, the final executable you are trying to build depends on `functionsLab1.o`.  You can probably make your entire Makefile:

```
main: main.o functionsLab1.o
```

(Yes, literally one line.). That ignores the dependency on the header file, but it should work for you.  Let `make` use its default rules; they are pretty good.  If you want to include the header dependency, do something like:

```
main: main.o functionsLab1.o
main.o: main.c  functionsLab1.h
functionsLab1.o: functionsLab1.c  functionsLab1.h
```

If for some reason you really want to be explicit (you don't!), you can do:

```
main: main.o functionsLab1.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $?   # Warning: incomplete.  See note below

main.o: main.c  functionsLab1.h
functionsLab1.o: functionsLab1.c  functionsLab1.h
```

Again, letting `make` use its default rules to construct the object files.  You *can* override the default rules, but there is very seldom a reason to do so.  Indeed, this is an excellent example where attempting to override the default rule gives you a sub-optimal recipe.  The default rule would be something like `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $? $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)`, and many users would reasonably expect to be able to specify LDLIBS. The example shown above ignores LDLIBS, violating the principal of least surprise.